# Angular Use a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am build an app and I would like to use the Twit API, however for some reason I can't get the code to work in a typescript file

so I made a js file in the directory

[image]

and here is the code that is in dashboard.page.js (of course the keys have been removed for security)

```
var Twit = require('twit')

  var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         '...',
    consumer_secret:      '...',
    access_token:         '...',
    access_token_secret:  '...',

  })

  //
  //  tweet 'hello world!'
  //


  function sendTweet(){
    T.post('statuses/update', { status: 'hello CarlLLL' }, function(err, data, response) {
        console.log(data)
      })
  }
```

and here some code from dashboard.page.html

```
  <ion-row class="ion-justify-content-center">
          <ion-col size=" 12">
              <div class = "imageBox"  (click) ="startCountdown(5)" onclick= 'sendTweet();'> 
              <!-- <div class = "imageBox"  (click) ="shareFacebook()">  -->
            <img src="../../assets/help_btn.png" style="width :100%;">           
              <div class = "imageText">{{imageText}}</div>           
            </div>

          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
```

and the error I get is

```
ReferenceError: sendTweet is not defined
```

I would like to know how one can call a function from my javascript file into the html page

Comment: you need to write this function inside same component

Comment: Are you sure you can use this Twitter client in the browser (Ionic app)? Reading through its documentation I think it's only for Node.js (server-side).